# Laravel/Eloquent query going wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, one with users, one with the name of their document. The first table consists of two columns: id and username. The second one consists of three columns: id, userid and document_name.

Now, I'm trying to create a query in the controller. What should happen, ideally, is that if someone visits `website.com/{documentname}`, it displays the username of the owner. Also, this should only happen if the current logged in user is the owner of the document. However, this is proving more difficult than I imagined. As in, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the query:

```
$user = DB::table('documents')
            ->join('users', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('users.id', '=', 'documents.userid')
                     ->where('documents.userid', '=', Auth::id())
                     ->where('documents.document_name', '=', $document_name);
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$document_name` isn't in scope for the join function: you need to pass it through to the closure via `use`

```
$user = DB::table('documents')
        ->join('users', function($join) use ($document_name)
        {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'documents.userid')
                 ->where('documents.userid', '=', Auth::id())
                 ->where('documents.document_name', '=', $document_name);
        })
        ->get();
```

**EDIT**

Because the WHERE conditions apply to the base table, and not to the JOIN:

```
$user = DB::table('documents')
        ->join('users', function($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'documents.userid')
        })
        ->where('userid', '=', Auth::id())
        ->where('document_name', '=', $document_name);
        ->get();
```

Comment: Okay, so now if I do `{{ $user->username }}` I get `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Enable database logging in `config/database.php` to see just what SQL query is actually being built

Comment: `select * from documents inner join users on users.id =  documents.id and documents.userid = '1' and documents.document_name = 'testdoc'`

Comment: So you really should be applying the `where` clauses ___outside___ of the JOIN

Answer (score 2):

```
  **Try this query :** 



 $user =  DB::table('documents')
  ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'documents.userid')
  ->where('documents.userid', '=', Auth::id())
  ->where('documents.document_name', '=', $document_name);
  ->get();
```